# Dependencies installed with Dockerfile are inaccessible in later pipeline steps. How to enable?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Currently using Jenkins Blue Ocean to try and setup a new pipeline. It's a node based project and I am running `npm install` within the Dockerfile with success, however later pipeline steps do not see the installed `node_modules`. This behaviour is rather strange.

Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      filename 'Dockerfile.prod'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'ls node_modules'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:8

ADD . /var/www    
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN ["npm", "install"]
```

During Dockerfile build:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN ["npm", "install"]

 ---> Running in de3cd138a40e
...
added 1283 packages in 39.842s

Removing intermediate container de3cd138a40e
```

Within the `test` stage of the Jenkinsfile:

```
+ ls node_modules

ls: cannot access node_modules: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have never used this set up, but are you sure that your `ls node_nodules` command is running inside the container? Your `Dockerfile` is installing all dependencies inside Docker image and thus they are not accessible outside without running the container.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @IgorNikolaev! So according to the docs found here https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-example if the dockerfile agent is defined at the root level all stages should be executed within it.. 

I tried setting an ENV inside the Dockerfile and when I run the sh step it is echo'ing the correct value. Weirdness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. After Jenkins compiles the initial dockerfile, for the later pipeline steps it properly launches it. However, if one views the job logs (not in the blueocean view), one can see that Jenkins then overrides the `WORKDIR` while launching the container `docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/workspace_name`. Therefore one needs to manually navigate to the expected `WORKDIR`.

Comment: According to documentation you can also provide additional `args` when building a container. So what you could try is to set `WORKDIR` dynamically. For that you would need to define an environment variable which you can then assign to `WORKDIR`. But Docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) says you can only use environment variable explicitly set in `Dockerfile` but you could use `ARG` to pass a value for `ENV` :)

Comment: But that would also mean that you can't reuse the image for subsequent build unless you install your node modules globally.

Comment: For sure, it seems like if you try to pass in a `-w` jenkins takes precedence since it's later on. Wish it was configurable, but I saw a few related issues open so hopefully it gets resolved.

Comment: @dmitri-farkov what exactly did you do? Because I tried passing args to docker, but it didn't work.